# #define displayed output where it shouldn't

Tags: qt, global-variables

I'm trying to manage my own `Debug system` on `Qt` but I have some issues :

main.h

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "PhTools/PhDebug.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Test of Debug tool
    DEBUG << "Test";

    // Test of TimeCode
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
    {
        if(false)
            DEBUG << "problem with me";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

PhDebug.h

```
#ifndef PHDEBUG_H
#define PHDEBUG_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QDate>
#include <QRect>

#define DEBUG PhDebug d; d <<  PHDEBUG

#define PHDEBUG  qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << ":"

// In order to get rid of double quotes when displaying a variable
#define Q(string) (string).toStdString().c_str()

class PhDebug
{
public:
    QDebug operator<<(QDebug dbg)
    {
        QString d;
        d = QDate::currentDate().toString("dd.MM.yyyy");
        d += " - ";
        d += QTime::currentTime().toString("hh.mm.ss.zzz");
        d += " in";
        dbg << Q(d);

        return dbg;
    }

};

#endif // PHDEBUG_H
```

So the output should be `04.09.2013 - 12.30.51.513 in main : Test` but instead I have this :

```
04.09.2013 - 12.30.51.513 in main : Test 
04.09.2013 - 12.30.51.514 in main : problem with me 
04.09.2013 - 12.30.51.514 in main : problem with me 
04.09.2013 - 12.30.51.514 in main : problem with me
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is lack of braces around `if(false)`.  The `d <<  PHDEBUG` part of your macro still gets executed.

Incidentally, Qt already has a helper that does the same thing as your Q macro: qPrintable